# Compact way to initialize an array of structures in C?

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, structure

I've got a rather messy way to initialize an array of structures, and I'm hoping someone can help me find a more compact method. My structure is:

```
struct Vertex_t {
  int i; /* Label */
  int n; /* Order (number of 2D simplicies it is contained within) */
  int r[3]; /* Position of vertex, for plotting */
};
```

And I need a bunch of these, so I'm preparing an array of them:

```
struct Vertex_t v_list[VERT_MAX]
```

So now I need to set the ones I'm initially using (4 here, but in principle, it will be more):

```
int N_t=4;
for (i=0;i<N_v;i++){
    v_list[i].i=i;
    v_list[i].n=1;
}
v_list[0].r[0]=0;
v_list[0].r[1]=1;
v_list[0].r[2]=0;
.../* for each i*/
```

So I can loop through to set the initial numbers, but for the array r (playing the role of a 3D vector here), I have to set each one individually (each value of r[] must be set by hand....I think). The above works, but I'd much rather use something like

```
v_list[0].r[]={0,1,0};
```

or even

```
v_list[i]={.i=i,.n=1, .r={0,1,0}};
```

But I know neither of them works because I've already got the memory for v_list[i] reserved.

Does anyone have a way to get what I'm going for? I need a large number of structures in an array, and I'd like to set them as if I was initializing them.

Comment: `v_list[i]=(struct Vertex_t){.i=i,.n=1, .r={0,1,0}};`  Braces by themselves do not imply a type unless it is the declaration itself. Therefore, you need a cast.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a nested loop.

Comment: @Jason: I think that might be it!

Comment: @ScottHunter: In principle that would work, but many of these things need to be set by hand - in particular, the values of r[], depend on something complicated that aren't part of the code (and don't make much sense to include).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for the array r (playing the role of a 3D vector here), I have to set
> each one individually (each value of r[] must be set by hand....I
> think). The above works, but I'd much rather something like
>
> ```
> v_list[0].r[]={0,1,0};
> ```
>
> or even
>
> ```
> v_list[i]={.i=i,.n=1, .r={0,1,0}};
> ```

C has array *initialization* but not (whole-)array *assignment*.  If you want to avoid individual element assignments then these are some of your better options:

1. Use a *bona fide* initializer in the declaration instead of initialization code:

   ```
   struct Vertex_t v_list[VERT_MAX] = {
       { .i = 0, .n = 1, .r = {0, 0, 0} },
       { .i = 1, .n = 1, .r = {1, 1, 0} },
       { .i = 2, .n = 1, .r = {0, 1, 1} },
       { .i = 3, .n = 1, .r = {1, 0, 1} }
       // other elements will be default-initialized
   };
   ```
2. Assign from compound literal structures (the array inside does not prevent this):

   ```
   struct Vertex_t v_list[VERT_MAX];

   // Possibly this can be looped:
   v_list[0] = (struct Vertex_t) { .i = 0, .n = 1, .r = {0, 0, 0} };
   v_list[1] = (struct Vertex_t) { .i = 1, .n = 1, .r = {1, 1, 0} };
   v_list[2] = (struct Vertex_t) { .i = 2, .n = 1, .r = {0, 1, 1} };
   v_list[3] = (struct Vertex_t) { .i = 3, .n = 1, .r = {1, 0, 1} };
   // other elements of `v_list` are not initialized
   ```
3. `memcpy()` the array members from compound literals:

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       v_list[i].i=i;
       v_list[i].n=1;
   }
   memcpy(v_list[0].r, (int[]) {0, 0, 0}, sizeof(v_list[0].r));
   memcpy(v_list[1].r, (int[]) {1, 1, 0}, sizeof(v_list[1].r));
   memcpy(v_list[2].r, (int[]) {0, 1, 1}, sizeof(v_list[2].r));
   memcpy(v_list[3].r, (int[]) {1, 0, 1}, sizeof(v_list[3].r));
   ```
4. Like (3), but copy from local `static` arrays of `const int` instead of from compound literals.

Comment: If the elements of the `r` member array are all the same, option 2 with a loop makes the most sense.  If the elements of `r` can be calculated, option 2 with a loop still makes sense.  In fact, I think option 2 with a loop is probably the way to go.  It's a nuisance that C doesn't have a way to apply a single initializer repeatedly.  GCC supports `[1 ... 4] = { … }` (note the differences in the triple dots), but the space before the `...` is crucial because of the 'maximal munch' rule.  I'd like to see either `[1:4]` or perhaps `[1] ... [4]` used as those both avoid the mandatory space.

Comment: I agree, @JonathanLeffler, I like option (2) with a loop for all the cases that can be handled that way.  But it is not clear whether the OP's array elements indeed are constant or computable, and I assumed based on the OP's example code that they probably are not (else why would those assignments be done outside the loop?).

Comment: (See GCC [designated initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits) for information about GCC range-initialization.)

Comment: I've marked this as the answer, but yes, the elements in r[] are "not computable", or at least, "not easily computable and outside of the scope of what I'm asking." I actually like #2, but it's likely #1 is better practice since that uses default initialization.